# R vector creation from data

Tags: r

In r I'm trying to figure out how to find which areas are contained in A, B, C,D, etc. For instance, A contains 540, 300, 330. While C contains area 330.

I would like to save these to a vector so like A = [540,300,330] and C = [300], and D = [540, 330]

Data:

```
Area    A   B   C   D
540     Y           Y    
300     Y       Y
330     Y           Y
```

I was thinking of using a summaryBy Statement. But this doesn't give me the desired outcome.

```
 summaryBy(Area ~ A, FUN=(length))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a `list()` object containing what you want via:

```
lapply(dat[c("A","B","C","D")], function(x) dat$Area[x=="Y"] )
#$A
#[1] 540 300 330
#
#$B
#integer(0)
#
#$C
#[1] 300
#
#$D
#[1] 540 330
```

There is almost no reason to populate separate `A`, `B` etc variables.

You can wrap the above in `stack(...)` if you want a 'tidy' 2 column dataframe with the value and the index.

Comment: How about as input: `dat[-1]`?

Comment: @Parfait - sure, if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` is more complicated:

```
dat %>%
  gather(k,v,-Area) %>% 
  filter(v=="Y") %>%
  nest(Area) %>%
  as.data.frame

  k          data
1 A 540, 300, 330
2 C           300
3 D      540, 330
```

Butif you have `NA`s instead of empty strings, it's almost elegant:

```
df[df==""] <- NA

df %>%
  gather(k, v, -Area, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  nest(Area)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dM <- melt(setDT(dat), id.var = "Area")[value == "Y"]
split(dM$Area, dM$variable)
#$A
#[1] 540 300 330

#$B
#integer(0)

#$C
#[1] 300

#$D
#[1] 540 330
```

---

If we need a data.frame or matrix output

```
`dim<-`(dat$Area[row(dat[-1]) *NA^(dat[-1]!="Y")], dim(dat[-1]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  540   NA   NA  540
#[2,]  300   NA  300   NA
#[3,]  330   NA   NA  330
```